# automated publish/deploy Azure package to cloud

Tags: deployment, azure, msbuild

I would like to have CI to build and deploy Azure package to cloud staging.
I followed http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/common-tasks/continuous-delivery/#step4

The tutorial deploy from power shell script but it does not work. There  is an error as following...

Get-AzureDeployment : "An exception occurred when calling the ServiceManagement API. HTTP Status Code: 404. Service
Management Error Code: ResourceNotFound. Message: No deployments were found.. Operation Tracking ID:

Please point me to right direction.
I am not sure that the powershell is good one or there are other way to create MSBuild script to deploy Azure to cloud?

Answer (score 0):

Calling Get-AzureDeployment with a specific service name is going to assume you've already created the service (e.g. yourname.cloudapp.net). I don't know if you've done that already, but that's the first thing I'd do. The script you referenced in the tutorial takes care of creating a *deployment* within that service name, and even handles non-existent deployments. However, I don't see anything that creates the actual service for you, so this is probably why the script is failing. See item 7 in step 4:

```
New-AzureService -ServiceName "mytestcloudservice" -Location "North Central US" -Label "mytestcloudservice"
```

Hopefully that's the issue you're hitting.

Answer (score 0):

If have found my problem. Once i dig down in the pwoershell script. I need to change subscription name to follow my credentials.publishsettings file. After i change or specify in powershell script parameter. it works properly.

Param(  $serviceName = "",
        $storageAccountName = "",
        $packageLocation = "",
        $cloudConfigLocation = "",
        $environment = "Staging",
        $deploymentLabel = "ContinuousDeploy to $servicename",
        $timeStampFormat = "g",
        $alwaysDeleteExistingDeployments = 1,
        $enableDeploymentUpgrade = 1,
        **$selectedsubscription = "'3-Month Free Trial",**
        $subscriptionDataFile = ""
     )